# Creating DB records with a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create records with a rake task that would also update the record if they exist. However, when there aren't any records, the importer fails...

```
require 'csv'

namespace :importer do
  task names: :environment do

    total_rows = 0
    saved_rows = 0

    CSV.foreach('restaurant_names.csv', headers: true) do |row|
      number = row[0]
      record = Restaurant.find_or_create_by(number: number)
      record.update_attributes(
        name: row[1]
      )
      if record.save!
        saved_rows += 1
        total_rows += 1
      else
        total_rows += 1
      end

    end
        puts "#{saved_rows} out of #{total_rows} saved"
  end
```

... with the following error message

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: translation missing: es.activerecord.errors.messages.record_invalid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you attempt to create a record like this:

```
record = Restaurant.find_or_create_by(number: number)
```

you're getting the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
```

So something about a record with just a number, or having just a number with that value, is invalid. You can find out what it is like this:

```
record = Restaurant.new(number: number)
record.valid?  # calling this creates any validation errors
=> false
record.errors.messages
=> # this should explain what the invalid parts are.
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. It is in my model, I have validates_presence_of many other attributes other than number and name. Thanks